# calling Cancel() on CompletableFuture after get() is correct approch

Tags: multithreading

I writing this code to leverage the advantages of Completable future.

My doubt is call cancel() method after get() is correct approach?

```
 private void combineFilters(JobFilter jobFilter,
                            CompletableFuture<List<String>> measureCompletableFuture,
                            CompletableFuture<List<String>> dqTypCompletableFuture,
                            CompletableFuture<List<String>> ownerCompletableFuture,
                            CompletableFuture<List<String>> jobTypeCompletableFuture,
                            CompletableFuture<List<String>> jobStateCompletableFuture) {
    try {
        CompletableFuture.allOf(measureCompletableFuture, dqTypCompletableFuture,
                                ownerCompletableFuture, jobTypeCompletableFuture,
                                jobStateCompletableFuture)
                         .join();
        LOGGER.info("All filters DB calls completed");
        if (measureCompletableFuture.isDone()) {
            LOGGER.info("Populating measure filters results");
            jobFilter.setMeasureName(measureCompletableFuture.get());
        }
        if (dqTypCompletableFuture.isDone()) {
            LOGGER.info("Populating dqtype filters results");
            jobFilter.setDqType(dqTypCompletableFuture.get());
        }
        if (ownerCompletableFuture.isDone()) {
            LOGGER.info("Populating owner filters results");
            jobFilter.setOwner(ownerCompletableFuture.get());
        }
        if (jobTypeCompletableFuture.isDone()) {
            LOGGER.info("Populating jobtype filters results");
            jobFilter.setType(jobTypeCompletableFuture.get());
        }
        if (jobStateCompletableFuture.isDone()) {
            LOGGER.info("Populating jobstate filters results");
            jobFilter.setTriggerState(jobStateCompletableFuture.get());
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while populating the filter results {}",
                     e.getMessage());
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } finally {
        LOGGER.info("Exiting from combine job filters");
        measureCompletableFuture.cancel(true);
        dqTypCompletableFuture.cancel(true);
        ownerCompletableFuture.cancel(true);
        jobTypeCompletableFuture.cancel(true);
        jobStateCompletableFuture.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).